# how can make the background fade when the prograss bar appear?

Tags: android, progress-bar, material-design, image-uploading

I am uploading the images to the server. When the user click on the upload button the the 20 images will be uploaded and the progress bar will be shown. No i want to ask that how can i fade the whole Activity when the progress bar shown?[image]

Comment: Please share the code of what you've done so far

Comment: I would use use a [ProgressDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)

Comment: is the progress dialog is deprecated?

Comment: As of API 26 Yes. It still can be used. If you want something similar to it, I would create a custom view with a progress bar inside

Comment: can you send me some link?

Comment: i got you answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In solve this problem by using the Progress dialog.
This is the library which helps me to solve the problem.

https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs

1.Add this line in the build.gradle file

```
implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.6.0'
```

2.Set the onclick listener on button

```
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .title("Title")
                        .content("Content")
                        .progress(true,100).show();
            }
        });
```